# How does the Kotlin/Native compiler handle polymorphism?

Tags: kotlin-native

In a personal project of mine on Kotlin/JVM, I was told that I should avoid polymorphic method calls in performance sensitive code. Wondering why this was the case, I ended up finding [this article](https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/16-megamorphic-virtual-calls) which highlights why.

Naturally, I wondered *why* this limitation was necessary. Can Kotlin/Native avoid virtual method table lookups by enforcing polymorphism just at compile time? Consider the following example.

```kotlin
interface A {
    fun foo()
}

class B : A { 
    override fun foo() = Unit 
}

class C : A { 
    override fun foo() = println("")
}

val bar = listOf(B(), C())
bar.forEach {
    it.foo()
}
```

In the current version of the Kotlin/Native compiler (1.4.20), are virtual method lookups necessary for the above example? Furthermore, *are they theoretically necessary*? Can the above code be completely enforced by the compiler?

Comment: This is a really good question--it relates directly to performance.  It's been two and half years; why has no one addressed it?